# Detect changed files

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, vbscript

How to detect **changed files** and move them to a folder named **storage** on my **desktop** is there any way I can do it with powershell/bat/vbscript **without** any third party tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET framework has [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0), which can be accessed from PowerShell ([example](https://powershell.one/tricks/filesystem/filesystemwatcher)).

Answer (score 1):

This will print out newly created files in `c:\win16`. Note the double doubled backslashes in the folder path. `Within 10` says to check every 10 seconds.

This copies new files in `C:\Win16` to `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Backup\`. Note trailing backslash. You need to edit the paths.

All the `Replace`s and `Split`s are getting it a a plain file path turning two backslashes to one, removing quotes, and `split` discards the first part of the returned string.

Call it `monitorfolder.vbs`.

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\Win16""'")
Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    FSO.MoveFile Replace(Replace(Split(objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent, "=")(1), "\\", "\"), """", ""), "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Backup\"
Loop
```

---

**To print it out to a console window**

*Shift+Right Click* on the file - *Copy As Path*. Open Command Prompt as Administrator and
*Right Click - Paste*, then press *Home* key and prepend `cscript //nologo`  to the path to the vbs. Then press *Ctrl+C* to stop monitoring.

The output will look like this

```
C:\Windows\system32>cscript //nologo "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Bat+Vbs\monitorfolder.vbs"
"c:\Win16\file.txt"
"c:\Win16\Folder Property List.txt"
"c:\Win16\IHS.pdf"
"c:\Win16\nfs3.exe - Shortcut.lnk"
```

---

**Note**

When a file is modified or created Windows sets its Archive bit. `XCopy` can copy only files with the archive bit set and then clear the bit. This is how early MS-Dos backup programs worked. It only copies new of modified files since the last backup. See `attrib /?` and `xcopy /?`.

Comment: what about moving it?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/movefile-method

Comment: What does the impersonation code mean

Comment: It is impersonating you. In the past you could be anonymous etc. This is the only useful one left. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.impersonationlevel?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0 This means WMI will only do what you are allowed to do.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala As you didn't ask the question you wasted my time.

Comment: Lol ok buddy!:)

Comment: Why shouldn't someone else ask something about someone's answer? Since when are only those who post the original question allowed to do that?

Answer (score 1):

possible solution, run powershell script every like 10 minutes, look for created/modified files and move

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? { $_.CreationTime -gt $(get-date).AddMinutes(-10)} | % { Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $(Join-Path  -Path $([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath source) }
```